# List installed font names in Windows 10 Universal App

Tags: c#, fonts, windows-10, win-universal-app, sharpdx

I am building a Windows 10 universal app in C# that has to list the names of the installed fonts on the system. The app was a metro/modern ui/windows 8.1 app and I used [the SharpDX 'trick'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29588696/how-to-fill-combobox-with-list-of-available-fonts-in-windows-8-metro-store-app-u?rq=1) there to get the names.

SharpDX is not available (yet?) for Windows 10 UAP, so that does not work anymore.

Any other ways to achieve my goal? Should I consider a fixed list of font names as described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh700394.aspx) under recommended fonts? This seems rather limiting when on a desktop for instance.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: FYI, SharpDX 3.0.0-beta+ is compatible with Windows 10 UAP

Comment: Thank you xoofx, good to know!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Same basic idea: you'll still use DirectWrite to get the font names.

You can use [Win2D](http://microsoft.github.io/Win2D/html/Introduction.htm) to get to DirectWrite from C# in both Windows 8.1 and Universal Windows Platform apps. CanvasTextFormat.[GetSystemFontFamilies](http://microsoft.github.io/Win2D/html/M_Microsoft_Graphics_Canvas_Text_CanvasTextFormat_GetSystemFontFamilies_1.htm) will return the font families:

```
string[] fonts = Microsoft.Graphics.Canvas.Text.CanvasTextFormat.GetSystemFontFamilies();
foreach (string font in fonts)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Font: {0}", font));
}
```

Comment: Awesome! I tried SharpDX for font enumeration in windows 8.1. It's works fine but failed on certification (WACK) cause of deprecated API in dll - D2D1GetGradientMeshInteriorPointsFromCoonsPatch.

Answer (score 2):

I decided for the fixed list approach. It does not require Win2D.

If someone is interested, here is the list of fonts that are guaranteed to be available in all Windows 10 editions that support UWP apps:

Parsed from [https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh700394.aspx](https://web.archive.org/web/20150715105326/https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh700394.aspx)

```
public static string[] FontNames = {
    "Arial", "Calibri", "Cambria", "Cambria Math", "Comic Sans MS", "Courier New",
    "Ebrima", "Gadugi", "Georgia",
    "Javanese Text Regular Fallback font for Javanese script", "Leelawadee UI",
    "Lucida Console", "Malgun Gothic", "Microsoft Himalaya", "Microsoft JhengHei",
    "Microsoft JhengHei UI", "Microsoft New Tai Lue", "Microsoft PhagsPa",
    "Microsoft Tai Le", "Microsoft YaHei", "Microsoft YaHei UI",
    "Microsoft Yi Baiti", "Mongolian Baiti", "MV Boli", "Myanmar Text",
    "Nirmala UI", "Segoe MDL2 Assets", "Segoe Print", "Segoe UI", "Segoe UI Emoji",
    "Segoe UI Historic", "Segoe UI Symbol", "SimSun", "Times New Roman",
    "Trebuchet MS", "Verdana", "Webdings", "Wingdings", "Yu Gothic",
    "Yu Gothic UI"
};
```

Particularly, for my application, I removed from this list a few that do not interest me, like `Javanese Text Regular Fallback font for Javanese script` plus those `Microsoft *` asian languages and `Segoe MDL2 Assets` plus `(Web|Wing)dings` which are only for icons.

Comment: A newer version of a similar page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/fonts/windows_10_font_list.